# SWCrypt public key VS PKCS8PEM Key

Tags: ios, swift, rsa

I want to user SWCrypt for RSA encryption and decryption. i should send my public key base64 decoded to server. but when i try send generated public key base64 i can't get this error in server side:

```
let (privateKey, publicKey) = try CC.RSA.generateKeyPair(2048)
let publicKeyBase64 = publicKey.base64EncodedString()
```

error: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence

but when send PEMPublicKey getting successfully response.

```
let publicKeyPEM = SwKeyConvert.PublicKey.derToPKCS8PEM(publicKey)
```

what is difference between  publicKeyBase64 and publicKeyPEM?

sample of generated key:

```
MIIBCgKCAQEAuWwCZpNXJtT2spBsDwrQaTFGVAjicM341Qzg+1whtlj9J60c/7HYe6AcGHa8Dinkiuk7Whs1Wpa34aa223WQsa+kFSNwkC6oDUXhewan3VEsv1uedzHc8JPlTXnItJsP8cIETFgHpdKWk462hU09mVCTtQTix0BEb8snS96wERvKq957OeaGtFasfT/bQfY0mbDu6eEMqswmfX8j84kuTfwWtqt6mLMTJaDwnsGc5WY1zkau68IQ/CBiiLpZ5hSVMs2pPj3Ao0+wNhR5MlMgdcwrU62SHWcMJ5cYssFgWZyZSvO3n/yW43fE5a1i+9Tm2trveGIdMR4d/MoA79/8IQIDAQAB
```

sample of generated PEM key :

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuWwCZpNXJtT2spBsDwrQaTFGVAjicM341Qzg+1whtlj9J60c/7HYe6AcGHa8Dinkiuk7Whs1Wpa34aa223WQsa+kFSNwkC6oDUXhewan3VEsv1uedzHc8JPlTXnItJsP8cIETFgHpdKWk462hU09mVCTtQTix0BEb8snS96wERvKq957OeaGtFasfT/bQfY0mbDu6eEMqswmfX8j84kuTfwWtqt6mLMTJaDwnsGc5WY1zkau68IQ/CBiiLpZ5hSVMs2pPj3Ao0+wNhR5MlMgdcwrU62SHWcMJ5cYssFgWZyZSvO3n/yW43fE5a1i+9Tm2trveGIdMR4d/MoA79/8IQIDAQAB
```

how can send generated public key simple of PEM key format?

thanks.

Comment: What format is expecting your server: DER (binary), PEM (base64 encoded with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY------), or DER encoded in base64?

Comment: @pedrofb PKCS8 for private key and  X509 for public key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X509 is a standard for Public Key Infraestructure, not a encoding format. You can encode a X509 public key in `PEM` (base64), `DER`(binary) or `XML`. Also the binary data of the public key can be represented in `PCKS#1` or `X509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo`.

In my knowledge PKCS#8 is a standard for private keys. See [PKCS #8: Private-Key Information Syntax Standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5208.txt). So I guess  [SWCrypt](https://github.com/soyersoyer/SwCrypt) is really using X509 `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` (Maybe i have not read some RFCs), which is what your server is waiting for.

```
let publicKeyPEM = SwKeyConvert.PublicKey.derToPKCS8PEM(publicKey)
```

`SubjectPublicKeyInfo` encapsulates the public key into a ASN.1 structure adding a header. If you encode the raw data of the public key (DER) using  `publicKey.base64EncodedString`, that header is not added and your server does not know how to manage it.

Comment: What I realized was is when I'm sending a PEM key that is base64 of generated public key, and And thats why i got successful response. So now when i send PEM key for server server detect this is my public key and encrypt send data with this key and i can decrypt server send data with own private key ?

Comment: RSA encryption is done with the public key and decryption with the private key, so your server can send data to you encrypted with the public key. Note that RSA encryption is limited by key size, so this schema is valid for small sizes

Comment: that means when server encrypt data with PEM key i cant decrypt this data with my private key ?

Comment: When server encrypt data with PEM key you CAN decrypt this data with the private key